# Private tor network set up

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, network-configuration

I am working on tor network security. I planned to set up my tor node setup with 3 nodes : entry,middle and exit node. I don't want to work on real time client's data.

- Is it any way to not publish my nodes to the tor authoritative directory so that I can only use it for my research purpose?
- If it is possible, can you force my tor browser to use only my unpublished tor nodes?
  I configured shadow locally and there is no proper documentation for setting up a entire 3 node tor architecture. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Chutney](https://gitweb.torproject.org/chutney.git/) makes it easy to set up a testing tor network.

---

> Is it any way to not publish my nodes to the tor authoritative directory so that I can only use it for my research purpose?

Yes. You tell them to publish to *your* authorities instead.

> If it is possible, can you force my tor browser to use only my unpublished tor nodes

By configuring the Tor that Tor Browser runs in the background to connect to *your* tor network instead, yes.